# Traceback (most recent call last): \Programs\Preprocessing.py", line 50, in tweet = json.loads(line)

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, analysis

```
emoticons_str = r"""
(?:
    [:=;] # Eyes
    [oO\-]? # Nose (optional)
    [D\)\]\(\]/\\OpP] # Mouth
)"""

regex_str = [
emoticons_str,
r'<[^>]+>', # HTML tags
r'(?:@[\w_]+)', # @-mentions
r"(?:\#+[\w_]+[\w\'_\-]*[\w_]+)", # hash-tags
r'http[s]?://(?:[a-z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-f][0-9a-f]))+', # URLs

r'(?:(?:\d+,?)+(?:\.?\d+)?)', # numbers
r"(?:[a-z][a-z'\-_]+[a-z])", # words with - and '
r'(?:[\w_]+)', # other words
r'(?:\S)' # anything else
]

 tokens_re = re.compile(r'('+'|'.join(regex_str)+')', re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)
 emoticon_re = re.compile(r'^'+emoticons_str+'$', re.VERBOSE | re.IGNORECASE)

 def tokenize(s):
return tokens_re.findall(s)

 def preprocess(s, lowercase=False):
 tokens = tokenize(s)
if lowercase:
    tokens = [token if emoticon_re.search(token) else token.lower() for token in tokens]
return tokens
punctuation = list(string.punctuation)
stop = stopwords.words('english') + punctuation + ['rt', 'via'] 
fname = 'Againpls.json'
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
lis=[]
neg=0.0
n=0.0
net=0.0
pos=0.0
p=0.0
count_all = Counter()
cout=0
for line in f:
    tweet = json.loads(line)
    # Create a list with all the terms
    blob = TextBlob(tweet["text"])
    cout+=1
    lis.append(blob.sentiment.polarity)
    #print blob.sentiment.subjectivity
    #print (os.listdir(tweet["text"]))
    if blob.sentiment.polarity < 0:
        sentiment = "negative"
        neg+=blob.sentiment.polarity
        n+=1
    elif blob.sentiment.polarity == 0:
        sentiment = "neutral"
        net+=1
    else:
        sentiment = "positive"
        pos+=blob.sentiment.polarity
        p+=1

    # output sentiment

print ("Total tweets"),len(lis)
print ("Positive "),float(p/cout)*100,"%"
print ("Negative "),float(n/cout)*100,"%"
print ("Neutral "),float(net/len(lis))*100,"%"
#print lis
    # determine if sentiment is positive, negative, or neutral

    # output sentiment
    #print sentiment
```

I'm using python 3.6 and i'm getting the following error when this line runs. tweet = json.loads(line) Any suggestions of what I might be doing wrong? The file does exist, but maybe not liking the values in the python.json file?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\etang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Preprocessing.py", line 50, in 
tweet = json.loads(line)
File "C:\Users\etang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json_init_.py", line 354, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "C:\Users\etang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\etang\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)
```

Comment: What's `line`? What is the file? You need to show the code you are using because how else do you expect people to help you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry about that. I have updated the code. Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and fix the code formatting/indentation.